# We painted the wall green. (adjective or noun?)

Tags: complements

> We painted the wall green.

The word 'green' in the above sentence is an adjective or a noun?

Comment: "*We washed the wall **clean**.*" Is "clean" a noun or an adjective? Similarly, why is this sentence wrong? "**We painted the wall latex.*"

Comment: @gotube We painted the wall 'in' green. Does this one sound okay? I think it's okay and in this case of 'in' green is a 'noun'.

Comment: No, "we painted the wall in green" doesn't sound okay. And "in green" isn't a noun.

Comment: @Divizna In 'in green', 'green' is a noun and 'in' is a prepostion.

Comment: Actually, the only noun in the phrase is "colour", which isn't there because the phrase employs an ellipsis. In any case, "in green" is not a noun but a prepositional phrase. Not to mention you still can't say "we painted the wall in green". You can say "we also have this T-shirt in green" (in addition to the white one you see).

Comment: @Divizna If I say "We painted the wall in greeen color"., is this okay?

Comment: @BEBYGONES This is veering into proofreading. What do you actually want to know? The sentence in your OP is correct and natural. From my comment, do you now know what part of speech "green" is? Is your question answered?

Comment: @gotube In "We painted the wall in greeen color." Why 'in green' instead of 'in green color' is wrong?

Comment: This could be a great question but it sorely lacks detail and research. I mean, you need to share the work you put into the question, don't leave it in your head. You should post the dictionary definition that says *green* is a noun and ask whether we agree or not and why.

Answer (score 1):

It's absolutely an adjective so I don't see any problems